# How to resolve Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tags: c#, asp.net

Beating my head against the wall on the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
See code below.  The offending line is marked with <!--->>>>>>>

```
string htmlOutput = " ";

    htmlOutput +=  "<h3>employee: " + employee.lastName + ", " + employee.firstName + " (" + thisForm.employeeID + ")</h3>" +
        "<h3>Submitted To: " + thisForm.boss + "</h3>" +

    if (job1.JRN != "" || job1.JRN != "INVALID")
    {
        <!--->>>>>>>htmlOutput += "<hr /><h4>Job 1</h4> " + "<h3>" + database.getjobName(job1.JRN) + " (" + job1.JRN + ")</h3>";
        htmlOutput += "<h3>Date of Last Attendance: " + job1.month + " " + job1.day + ", " + job1.year + "</h3>";
        htmlOutput += "<h3>Pass/Fail: " + job1.passFail + "</h3>";
    }
```

Comment: where do you define `database` and initialize it?

Comment: Debug your code and see if "database" really is an object reference when the code reaches that line. The error code makes it pretty clear what's wrong, and we need to see more of your code to help you.

Comment: You should really be using a `StringBuilder` when doing this much string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.Format("{0}{1}", obj1, obj2 ?? "")`. And use debugger, put breakpoint to this line and inspect objects, then add validation logic. Maybe the problem is in `database.getjobName` method code. You can always use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). Never use string concatenation like in your example, it's very ugly and error prone.